# Python: Using Tuples get filtered list

Tags: python, tuples

Input Format :
            The first line of input is an integer that corresponds to the number of records, 'n'.
            The next 'n' line corresponds to the records.
            The last line of input consists of the date to be filtered.

Output format :
            The first line of the output is a set of comma seperated strings containing the cargo name and date. 
        The next lines consists of the names of the cargos printed one next to the other seperated by new line.
        Refer to sample input and output for formatting specifications and more details.

Sample Input 1:

```
5
Allegan,11-12-2013
Douglas,29-12-2016
Junkers,27-03-2017
Biruinta,10-04-2014
ABC,27-03-2017
27-03-2016
```

Expected Sample Output 1:

```
[('Allegan', '11-12-2013'), ('Douglas', '29-12-2016'), ('Junkers', '27-03-2017'), ('Biruinta', '10-04-2014'), ('ABC', '27-03-2017')]
Douglas
Junkers
ABC
```

Code that was written:

```
n=int(input())
list1=[]
i=0
for i in range(0,n):
   string1=raw_input()
   i+=1
   string1=string1.split()
for item in string1:
  list1.append(item)
dateformat=raw_input()
mutuple = tuple(list1)
```

I am unable to split input from my list and get desired output by comparing as per the question. Can you please help

Comment: It is not clear what parts of this are from the problem and what parts are your attempt. Is the last code snippet your attempt, with everything preceding that the problem?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Updated the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the delimiters to the split function:

```
In [1]: "a,b,c,d,e,f".split(",")
Out[1]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

I also wouldn't do `string1=string1.split()`, because the return of `split` is
a list and the variable is called `string`. Sure it's not incorrect, but that
might confuse you later more than it helps.

Also

```
for item in string1:
    list1.append(item)
...
mutuple = tuple(list1)
```

is redundant, you just can do `mutuple = tuple(string1)`. But that's not
probably what you want.

```
long_list = []
ls = tuple("a,b".split(","))
long_list.append(ls)
ls = tuple("c,d".split(","))
long_list.append(ls)
print long_list

# prints [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
```